# Two Spring Boot modules in the same IntelliJ instance - one of them not starting up

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a rather strange situation, and I'm not even sure where I should be start looking...

I have three Maven projects in my IntelliJ, one is a common library for the other two.

When booting one of the two, it runs just fine.
But when I try booting up the second, it no longer works. I get a

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

The same thing happens when I boot up the second, it runs fine, but when I boot up the first, it doesn't work.

The workaround for this was to open up a second instance of IntelliJ, and open one of the two projects there, individually.
Then, running the first project in one IntelliJ instance works, and running the second project, in the other IntelliJ instance also works.

Database is Microsoft SQL Server. I have checked to have support for multi-connections.

Has anybody else, reading this, encountered something similar?
Any tips where I could start looking at...?

Comment: Note that IntelliJ IDEA always runs in a single instance (one process), even if you have multiple projects open. So it's not clear why opening the project in a different frame fixes it. Might be something specific to JDBC configuration or the options used in run configurations. Would be hard to guess without the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are right, but I tried reproducing it with a new project, from the ground-up, with DB connection and all, but it did not reproduce. This project was just handed to me, so I guess I'll just do the workaround, or maybe tinker it a bit more. Thanks anyway!